# How to finish a socket file transfer in Python?

Tags: python, sockets, tcp, file-transfer

I have a Client and a Server and I need to transfer some files using sockets. I can send small messages, but when I try to send a File, the problems begins...

client.py:

```
from socket import *
from threading import Thread
import sys
import hashlib

class Client(object):

    ASK_LIST_FILES    = "#001" # 001 is the requisition code to list 
                               # all the files
    ASK_SPECIFIC_FILE = "#002" # 002 is the requisition code to a 
                               # specific file
    SEND_FILE         = "#003" # 003 is the requisition code to send one 
                               # file
    AUTHENTICATION    = "#004" # 004 is the requisition code to user
                               # authentication

    listOfFiles = []

    def __init__(self):
        try:
            self.clientSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
        except (error):
            print("Failed to create a Socket.")
            sys.exit()


    def connect(self, addr):
        try:
            self.clientSocket.connect(addr)
        except (error):
            print("Failed to connect.")
            sys.exit()

        print(self.clientSocket.recv(1024).decode())

    def closeConnection(self):
        self.clientSocket.close()

    def _askFileList(self):
        try:
            data = Client.ASK_LIST_FILES
            self.clientSocket.sendall(data.encode())
            # self._recvFileList()
        except (error):
            print("Failed asking for the list of files.")
            self.closeConnection()
            sys.exit()

        thread = Thread(target = self._recvFileList)
        thread.start()

    def _recvFileList(self):
        print("Waiting for the list...")
        self.listOfFiles = []
        while len(self.listOfFiles) == 0:
            data = self.clientSocket.recv(1024).decode()
            if (data):
                self.listOfFiles = data.split(',')
                if(len(self.listOfFiles) > 0):
                    print (self.listOfFiles)

    def _askForFile(self, fileIndex):

        fileIndex = fileIndex - 1

        try:
            data = Client.ASK_SPECIFIC_FILE + "#" + str(fileIndex)
            self.clientSocket.sendall(data.encode())
        except(error):
            print("Failed to ask for an specific file.")
            self.closeConnection()
            sys.exit()

        self._downloadFile(fileIndex)

    def _downloadFile(self, fileIndex):
        print("Starting receiving file")
        f = open("_" + self.listOfFiles[fileIndex], "wb+")
        read = self.clientSocket.recv(1024)
        # print(read)
        # f.close
        while len(read) > 0:
            print(read)
            f.write(read)
            f.flush()
            read = self.clientSocket.recv(1024)
        f.flush()
        f.close()
        self.closeConnection()
```

server.py

```
from socket import *
from threading import Thread
import sys
import glob

class Server(object):

    def __init__(self):
        try:
            self.serverSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
        except (error):
            print("Failed to create a Socket.")
            sys.exit()

    def connect(self, addr):
        try:
            self.serverSocket.bind(addr)
        except (error):
            print ("Failed on binding.")
            sys.exit()

    def closeConnection(self):
        self.serverSocket.close()

    def waitClients(self, num):
        while True:
            print("Waiting for clients...")
            self.serverSocket.listen(num)
            conn, addr = self.serverSocket.accept()
            print("New client found...")
            thread = Thread(target = self.clientThread, args = (conn,))
            thread.start()

    def clientThread(self, conn):
        WELCOME_MSG = "Welcome to the server"
        conn.send(WELCOME_MSG.encode())
        while True:
            data = conn.recv(2024).decode()
            if(data):
                # print(data)
                # reply = 'OK: ' + data
                # conn.sendall(reply.encode())
                if(data == "#001"):
                    listOfFiles = self.getFileList()
                    strListOfFiles = ','.join(listOfFiles)
                    self._sendFileList(strListOfFiles, conn)
                else:
                    dataCode = data.split('#')
                    print(dataCode)
                    if(dataCode[1] == "002"):
                        print("Asking for file")
                        self._sendFile(int(dataCode[2]), conn)
                    if(dataCode[1] == "003"):
                        print("Pedido de login")
                        if self._authentication(dataCode[2]):
                            conn.send("OK".encode())
                            # self._recvFile(conn)
                        else:
                            conn.send("FAILED".encode())



    def _sendFile(self, fileIndex, conn):
        listOfFiles = self.getFileList()
        print(fileIndex)
        print(listOfFiles[fileIndex])
        f = open(listOfFiles[fileIndex], "rb")
        read = f.read(1024)
        while len(read) > 0:
            conn.send(read)
            read = f.read(1024)          
        f.close()

    def _sendFileList(self, strList, conn):
        try:
            conn.sendall(strList.encode())
        except (error):
            print("Failed to send list of files.")

    def getFileList(self):
        return glob.glob("files/*")
```

When I try to get a file from my server, I can transfer everything but the connection never ends. What is going on with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you are doing here the most common error using TCP: assume all data sent in a single send() will be got identically in a single recv(). This is untrue for TCP, because it is an *octet* stream, not a message stream. Your code will work only under ideal (lab) conditions and could mysteriously fail in a real world usage. You should either explicitly invent message boundaries in TCP streams, or switch e.g. to SCTP. The latter is available now almost everywhere and keeps message boundaries across a network connection.

The second your error is directly connected to the first one. When sending file, you don't provide any explicit mark that file has been finished. So, clients waits forever. You might try to close server connection to show that file is finished, but in that case client won't be able to distinguish real file end and connection loss; moreover, the connection won't be reusable for further commands. You would select one of the following ways:

- Prefix a file contents with its length. In this case, client will know how many bytes shall be received for the file.
- Send file contents as a chunk sequence, prefixing each chunk with its length (only for TCP) and with mark whether this chunk is last (for both transports). Alternatively, a special mark "EOF" can be sent without data.

Similarly, control messages and their responses shall be provided with either length prefix or a terminator which can't appear inside such message.

When you finish developing this, you would look at FTP and HTTP; both addresses all issues I described here but in principally different ways.